# Deleting substrings "dynamically" from a line in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a file with some lines in the text file like this

```
This is a test value with {MyTestValue = 0.34} How do I delete the test value? My line also has {MySecondTestValue = 0.35}
```

The value of `MyTestValue` is not the same value in each line.

Is there a way to determine the number of chars till the closing parenthesis and delete everything within the parentheses. So my output would be something like:

```
This is a test value with {}  How do I delete the test value? My line also has {MySecondTestValue = 0.35}
```

Comment: `and delete everything` ?

Comment: Is it surrounded by `{` and `}` ? Please provide examples of "before" and "after"

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: @Thomas, edited to reflect.

Comment: Have your text contains parenthesis '{' & '}' other than MyTestValue?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir, yes it does. You're right...

Comment: @MaskedAfrican, then you should edit your question and add this also.

Answer (score 3):

Possible implementation via *regular expressions*:

```
String source = "This is a test value with {MyTestValue = 0.34} How do I delete the test value?";

String result = Regex.Replace(source, "{.*}", (MatchEvaluator) ((match) => "{}"));
```

Comment: Let's hope the OP doesn't have nested braces... But nice solution anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
string line="This is a test value with {MyTestValue = 0.34} How do I delete the test value?";
int index1=line.indexOf('{');
int index2=line.indexOf('}');
line=line.Replace(line.Substring(index1,index2-index1),"");
```

Comment: I think it creates confusion when my text contains parenthesis other than MyTestValue.

Comment: Change it to `int index1=line.indexOf("{MyTestValue = ")`. Then it would be a great non-regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"{MyTestValue = [0-9.]+}", "{}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringbuilder is the most efficient way to work with strings. You can create custom method that works with it :

```
    static string[] ClearValues(string[] dirtyLines, string[] ignoreValuesList)
    {            
        string[] result = new string[dirtyLines.Length];
        bool ignore = false; StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();            

        for (int i = 0; i < dirtyLines.Length; i++)
        {                
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dirtyLines[i].Length; i2++)
            {
                if (dirtyLines[i][i2] == '{') { s2.Clear(); s.Append(dirtyLines[i][i2]); ignore = true; continue; }
                if (dirtyLines[i][i2] == '}') { if(ignoreValuesList.Contains(s2.ToString())) s.Append(s2.ToString()); s.Append(dirtyLines[i][i2]); ignore = false; continue; }
                if (!ignore) { s.Append(dirtyLines[i][i2]); } else { s2.Append(dirtyLines[i][i2]); }                    
            }
            result[i] = s.ToString();
            s.Clear();                
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Example of usage :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] dirtyLines = 
        {
            "This is a test value with {MyTestValue = 0.34} How do I delete the test value?",
            "This is {SomeOther = 11} How do I delete the test value?",
            "{X = 134} How do {Y = 500} I delete the {Z = 400}test value?",
        };

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        string[] clean = ClearValues(dirtyLines, new[] { "Y = 500", "Z = 400" });

        s.Stop();            

        for (int i = 0; i < clean.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clean[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nIt took {0} ms and {1} CPU ticks for method to execute", s.ElapsedMilliseconds, s.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How about situations where input =  `This is a test value with {MyTestValue = 0.34} How do I delete the test value? "My line also has {MySecondTestValue = 0.35}` and I need an output like:  `This is a test value with {}  How do I delete the test value? My line also has {MySecondTestValue = 0.35}`

Comment: Hmm, this might just do it, but in this case, I don't know what the value of Y and Z is on each line, All I know is I just want to preserve those values.